# Opacity to canvas without affecting inner image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem I have is on the image slider. The blue triangule is created using a multiply canvas effect seen here:
http://albertogasparin.it/articles/2011/05/html5-multiply-filter-canvas/

**I want the blue triangle to have it's `opacity to 0.5`**, but if I put that on the css *(canvas element)* it also affects the opacity of the image that's below. Any ideas how to achieve this?

This is my code:

```
    function to_canvas(im,w,h){
        var isIE8 = $.browser.msie && +$.browser.version === 8;
        var canvas;
        var imageBottom;
        var im_w = w;
        var im_h = h;
        var imgData;
        var pix;
        var pixcount = 0;
        var paintrow = 0;
        var multiplyColor = [70, 116, 145];
        var x_offset = Math.floor(($('#'+im).attr('width') - im_w)/2);
        var y_offset = Math.floor(($('#'+im).attr('height') - im_h)/2);
        if ( isIE8 ) {
            $('<div />' , {
                'id' : 'div-'+im,
                'class' : 'pseudo_canvas'
            }).css({
                'width' : im_w,
                'height' : im_h
            }).insertBefore('#'+im);
            $('#'+im).appendTo('#div-'+im).fadeIn();
            $('<img>' , {
                'src' : '/img/blueborder.png',
                'class' : 'blueborder'
            }).css({
            }).insertBefore('#'+im);
            $('#'+im).appendTo('#div-'+im).fadeIn();

        }else{
            imageBottom = document.getElementById(im);
            canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = im_w;
            canvas.height = im_h;
            imageBottom.parentNode.insertBefore(canvas, imageBottom);
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(imageBottom, -x_offset , -y_offset);
            imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            pix = imgData.data;
            for (var i = 0 ; i < pix.length; i += 4) {
                if(pixcount > im_w - (im_h - paintrow) ){
                    pix[i  ] = multiply(multiplyColor[0], pix[i  ]);
                    pix[i+1] = multiply(multiplyColor[1], pix[i+1]);
                    pix[i+2] = multiply(multiplyColor[2], pix[i+2]);
                }
                if(pixcount < im_w-1){
                    pixcount++;
                }else{
                    paintrow++;
                    pixcount = 0;
                }
            }
            ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
            /* $('#'+im).remove(); */
        }
    }
    function multiply(topValue, bottomValue){
        return topValue * bottomValue / 255;
    }
```

This is how I want the triangle color/opacity (obviously without the opacity of the image on the back):
[image]

Comment: if the triangle is always there why not put it in a different div places on top of it and change its opacity then?

Comment: because the triangle it's made of the canvas multiply effect, I can't put it on other div

Comment: might be a crappy workaround but just make an image of the triangle and solve as said above? Thats all I can come up with, im not sure its possible to do it any other way.

Comment: with the image it wouldn't work the "multiply" effect, it would be just opacity...

Answer (score 0):

if u have canvas-

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); 
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";//Change the color combination here
context.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
```

Comment: I put this and then no triangle is shown :) `Uncaught ReferenceError: context is not defined `

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Graphics/Drawing_graphics_with_canvas

Answer (score 0):

one way would be to use a semi-transparent background instead (e.g. png file)

Comment: Could you expand on this answer and maybe give an example to help the asker?